# axis label problem

Tags: plotting, labeling

I have a contourplot with (Greek) omega on the y-axis and Q^2 (GeV^2) on the x-axis. When I do

```
F1plot = ContourPlot[F1MEC[Q2, om], {Q2, 0.001, 2}, {om, 0., 1.0}, 
  Exclusions -> None, Axes -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {  Q^2 (GeV^2) , "\[Omega]"}, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

the y-axis is ok, but the x-axis has the order of the two ingredients interchanged. I get: GeV^2 Q^2 (without the parentheses). How do I get these into the correct order?

Comment: Use `"\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(Q\), \(2\)]\) (\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(GeV\), \
\(2\)]\))"`

Comment: ... or `FrameLabel -> {StringForm["`` ``", Q^2 , (GeV^2)], "\[Omega]"}`